Mutipart upload in GCS
I am trying to implement multipart upload in GCS but not finding any way to do that in Golang.
This is the doc I was going through.
How to implement multipart upload for GCS using Golang?

Do you want to code it by yourselves?

A multipart is MIME and each attachment state with two dashes on a new line.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

I have converted the XML requests to Golang for my usage but found no other way.
